# Enable ZendDebug in PhpStorm (MAC)

Tags: macos, debugging, zend-framework, phpstorm

I have 2 systems:

1. WIN7 + nginx + zend (fastcgi)
2. MAC + zend apache server

php.ini is the same on both systems.
phpinfo() shows that ZendDebugger is loaded and can accept on localhost

I develop in PhpStorm (v7.2 current). Php Web Application is configured same in both systems

On win using local www server + zend debug all is fine.
On mac, my breakpoints are not hit. Debug starts and I can see debug messages in the log window.

After reading some tutorials, I added an interpreter config to point to /usr/local/zend/bin and it is recognised as ZEND 5.3.27 with Zend Debugger.

Not sure where is the problem. I use same server configurations and after starting debug mode, breakpoints are working only on Windows.

Any thoughts?

Tnx

Comment: Missing path mappings? Any symbolic links used? Xdebug, for example, works with final/resolved paths only -- maybe the same needed for Zend Debugger as well? Also ... on Mac -- what path your project is in? Have you ever renamed any of the folders there? can you enable detailed Zend debugger logging and see what file it tries to debug?

Comment: No symlinks. Project is checked out from SVN in ~/Projects. What is interesting is debugger is listening to incoming connections from browser. Debugger starts to log all the info and warns from the code as is being executed. The "red" breakpoint doesn't have a steady arrow on it. The arrow blinks.

Comment: OOOPS: sorry LazyOne for misinformation. Practically found a symlink and now all is working! Tnx so much. Please make it as answer and I will mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is there any symbolic links in the project path? Xdebug, for example, works with final/resolved paths **only** -- Zend Debugger may do the same.
2. Have you ever renamed any folder in the project path (i.e. "myproject" to "myProject" etc)?
3. Enable detailed Zend Debugger logging and search for possible clues (what file it tries to debug etc).

Comment: thank you, found a Symlink from ~/Project/trunk to /usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs/